# phpMyAdmin : How to auto expand table tree-view in left navigation bar?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, whenever I open a table in new tab, the Left side Tree Navigation of database is always collapsed.

Is there any configuration tweak or something that I can do, so that the Tree Navigation auto expands for the current database?

Comment: How exactly are you opening a table in the new tab? Just trying to follow your workflow as closely as possible.

Comment: I'm opening the table in new tab, either by `right click -> new tab` or `ctrl+click`.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I don't believe there's a configuration directive to control this. You can see a lot of navigation-related directives [here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#navigation-panel-setup), but nothing seems related.

You may wish to open a [feature request](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/) about your idea.

Slightly related: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12158 (feature request to automatically expand when only one database is present, such as with the only_db directive).